# SSIS load from Oracle .NET client fails

Tags: sql-server, oracle11g

I have 1 ADO.NET source from Oracle 
and 1 ADO.NET destination in SQL Server.
And load fails with:

> [ADO NET Destination [16]] Error: An exception has occurred during
>   data insertion, the message returned from the provider is: Invalid
>   character value for cast specification.

**EDIT: ^^ this was fixed by setting the destination table column to nvarchar.**

If i try without any insert (just load all rows from source) it fails:

Now the error is :

> [ADO NET Source [432]] Error: The component "ADO NET Source" (432) was
>   unable to process the data. ORA-29275: partial multibyte character

Comment: The first error seems to indicate that you're getting data from Oracle OK as the error is in the target. The second error... what do you mean by 'without any insert'? Did you remove the destination component? How would you load all rows in this case?

Comment: just load the rows to ie. transformation component

Comment: Both errors mean that you've mixed ASCII and Unicode in your tables *and* transformations. If your SQL Server target table and the intermediate transformations have varchar columns(ASCII) but the source is Unicode, you can get errors all the way up to the source. You may have to refresh the columns in all steps to get rid of the errors. It's probably easier to start again using `nvarchar` throughout. As a rule, you should use `nvarchar` wherever possible unless you are *absolutely certain* your db will *never* receive data from another codepage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this when I found out the column with wrong datatype:

> select convert(column,'US7ASCII','WE8ISO8859P1') from table

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that your Oracle Client (client-side software that you need to access Oracle) have not configured properly. If you don't have Oracle Client installed, try [Oracle Instant Client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-100365.html). Check your client's `tnsnames.ora` file for valid server entry. Check that `TNS_ADMIN` environmental variable points to `tnsnames.ora` location. Make sure your Oracle Client binaries architecture matches your app (32 or 64-bit). You should be able to connect to Oracle from Visual Studio's Server Manager with .NET Oracle Data Provider.